# Algolia : Distinct with page

Tags: algolia

Am using the distinct clause for grouping content along with retrieving results page-by-page. But this ain't seem to be working. Getting zero matching results even though results are present.

Query filters being used as below.

```
{'hitsPerPage': 30, 'distinct': 5, 'filters': 'created>0', 'facetFilters': ['type:1', ['category:t1', 'category:abc', 'category:t2', 'category:t3']], 'page':1}
```

Comment: Did you select the attribute you want to distinct on? Also do you get results when not applying the `distinct`?

Comment: Yes for both. Attribute to distinct on is defined in the "Group By" section. Also when removing the distinct filter, I do get results back. Surprisingly if I set page to 0 i also get results back.

Comment: Arg yes, Algolia starts at page=0; it just means that you have less than 30 grouped hits, so the 2nd page (page=1) is empty.

Comment: "The hitsPerPage query parameter controls the number of companies per page. For example if you specify hitsPerPage=10 with distinct=3, you will have up to 30 hits in your search results (10 companies and a maximum of three offers per company). This behavior makes it easy to implement pagination with grouping." Does this mean that if any of the facets on which distinct is applied have < 3 hits then the 2nd page will not show up?

Comment: Also I have verified that each category has more than 1000 records each individually for the available filters. How is it that the # of grouped hits is < 30?

Comment: That's the point, the max number of hits you will get is number_of_distinct_cardinality*distinct_value. If you have 20 categories with 1000 records each and you do the distinct=3 on the "category" you'll still get 20*3=60 hits only.

Comment: Which makes sense that per-page you are returning a max of n-categories * k(distinct). But how does one navigate the grouped result set in a paginated manner? I am assuming the page param does the trick here, i.e setting page 0, causes the 1st 60 to be retrieved and page 1 the next 60.  In this case on specifying page 1 in the query param, I should also have had a set of another 60 records. Unfortunately, I don't see any records at all. +redox